# Is the set of prime numbers a regular language?

Tags: prime-numbers, computer-science, regular-language

I know that the language of prime numbers written in unary is not a regular language, but what about the prime numbers themselves? (When the alphabet is 0~9)
By intuition, I think it's not a regular language, but how to prove it?

Comment: You can use the pumping lemma.

Comment: Right, I'm sure of that too... but how, exactly? A nontrivial question.

Comment: This language is not even context-free. See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/786464)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generating function of the number of words of a given length
in a regular language is a rational function. This constrains
the growth rate of these numbers. By the Prime Number Theorem, the
number of primes of a given length (whether or not we admit leading
zeroes) does not grow at a rate compatible with the generating function
being rational.

Comment: This all sounds right, but a little more detail would be appreciated (by me, anyway).