# Binary prime numbers: grammar

Tags: automata, binary, formal-grammar

I want to write a grammar which produces binary prime numbers. But I can't find any patterns this grammar can be made of. Like this:

```
1. In binary all prime numbers except 2 begin and end with 1
2. Concatenation of 2 prime numbers is a prime number (not 100% sure about this...)
```

If I had a whole set of such rules, it wouldn't be hard to write a grammar.  Any information will be valuable for me!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [It would seem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785257/can-an-infinite-set-of-primes-be-a-regular-language-or-cfg) there's no context-free grammar whose language is the set of primes (or even an infinite subset of primes), though I don't really understand the proof. This is only a partial answer since maybe the primes could be generated by a more exotic grammar, though I doubt it.

Comment: @JackM Thank you for reply! I am talking about Type-0 and Type-1 grammars (Chomsky hierarchy) which describe Recursively enumerable and Context-sensitive languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not found such a patterns/rules so far... But I found another way to solve this problem.

I wrote Turing Machine which accepts binary primary numbers ([GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/aostrouhhov/9499c7419dca692338f137e9c9d5b202)). After that my friend wrote interpreter from TM to Grammar (examples can be found on GitHub). We got about 77000 productions in resulting Grammar. I believe this number can be reduced a lot, but this is another story anyway :)